# Binding TextBox to object WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to make the TextBox show the stringBody property of the CurrentDialog property of the window. Here's the XAML part:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="ComposerBox" Height="90.302" Margin="311,0,141.355,10" 
...
Text="{Binding Body}"
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"       
 VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
```

Here is a string from the windows constructor:

```
MessagingBox.DataContext = CurrentDialog;
```

I've also tried to set DataContext to this with no result.
Here's how CurrentDialog is defined:

```
private MessageDialog CurrentDialog { get; set; }
```

Here's the MessageDialog class definition:

```
   [Serializable][DataContract]
public class MessageDialog
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public UserData User { get; private set; }

    private List<Message> Dialog = new List<Message>();
    public string Body { get; private set; }

    public MessageDialog(UserData data)
    {
        Name = data.Username;
        User = data;
        Body = "";
    }

    public void Add(Message msg)
    {
        Dialog.Add(msg);
        Body += $"{msg.From}: {msg.Body} \n\n";
    }

}
```

}

The binding doesn't work at all. I also want it to be one-way.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem it's impossible to know for sure why your code isn't working. The proposed answer is a good guess though. If you expect the `Text` property to be updated when the source `Body` property is changed, you have to provide WPF some way to know when that actually happens. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is the usual way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Text="{Binding CurrentPerson.Body}"
> ```

Not sure why the binding path contains `CurrentPerson`, when it should be `CurrentDialog`, but even that isn't supposed to be there. Since the `DataContext` is already set to `CurrentDialog`, you can simply bind the text to :

```
Text="{Binding Body}"
```

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so the WPF know when the property changed:

```
[Serializable][DataContract]
public class MessageDialog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region public string Body
    private string m_Body;
    public string Body
    {
        get { return m_Body; }
        private set
        {
            if (m_Body == value)
                return;

            m_Body = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Text="{Binding CurrentPerson.Body}" is from one of the attempts, I removed it, still doesn't work